# Является ли здесь "вообще" вводным словом?

Tags: пунктуация

Вообще роль экспертного сообщества в нашем обществе сильно занижена.

Answer (score 2):

Если в значении "вообще говоря", то вводное, запятая нужна, я бы поставила. Если в значении "в общем и целом", или "всегда, при всех условиях", или "во всех отношениях" - это наречие, запятая не ставится. На Ваш выбор.

Answer (score 0):

Да, является. Вообще [говоря], роль экспертного сообщества...

Но сообщество рядом с обществом смотрится не очень.